# Elixir check if string is integer in guard

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to check if a string parameter being passed in is an integer? For example I need to retrieve a model based either on its id ("12345") or external_id ("eUv9wWzZ48bMZsuII6ivCle2NHgIEPoMLWC9ioDV"). Is this possible to achieve? I tried `is_integer` but that returns false as it doesn't try to parse a string.

```
def call(%{params: %{"id" => id}} = conn, module) when is_atom(module) and is_integer(id) do
    ZB.Repo.get!(module, id)
  |> check(conn)
end
def call(%{params: %{"id" => id}} = conn, module) when is_atom(module) do
  ZB.Repo.get_by!(module, external_id: id)
end
```

Comment: You should select @mudasobwa's answer instead of mine; mine is incorrect as he explained. :)

Comment: @Dogbert honestly, yours is perfectly correct, answering the question _stated_ :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and I believe you are trying to solve inexistent issue in an incorrect way :)

According to what I can see from your input, `external_id` is supposed to be the alphanumeric string of length 40. The keyword here is *alphanumeric*. That said, 40 times "1" might be an `external_id`. And you know what? It is perfectly parsed by [`Integer.parse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2):

```rb
iex|1 ▶ ["1"] |> List.duplicate(40) |> Enum.join |> Integer.parse
#⇒ {1111111111111111111111111111111111111111, ""}
```

That said, checking for integer is *invalid* in this context, because it might result in *false positive*.

What you do actually need to do, is to *try* to get the record by `external_id`, possibly based on it’s length or something, and fallback to `id` if not succeeded. Also, the length of binary *might be indeed checked in guard* (implicitly, by introducing an intermediate wrapper binary ⇒ bitstring.)

```rb
def call(%{params: %{"id" => id}} = conn, module) when is_atom(module) do
  case ZB.Repo.get_by(module, external_id: id) do
    {:ok, record} -> record
    _ -> ZB.Repo.get!(module, id) |> check(conn)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

No, this can't be done in a guard. The functions you can call in a guard is limited and does not include any function to check whether a string contains only digits.

You can instead use `Integer.parse/1` in the body:

```
def call(%{params: %{"id" => id}} = conn, module) when is_atom(module) do
  case Integer.parse(id) do
    {_, ""} -> 
      ZB.Repo.get!(module, id) |> check(conn)
    
    _ -> 
      ZB.Repo.get_by!(module, external_id: id)
  end
end
```